# Can't seem to parse using regxp and can't figure out why

Tags: applescript

In trying to parse some data from a string, I decided to use Satimage's regxp addition. However, I'm having some issues with it that I can't quite figure out. According to the documentation, the default regex engine is Ruby, which is great because it supports the lookbehind and lookahead and I can use those. I tested my regular expression in Ruby:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :056 >   ref = "ABCD_oxox\"><title>Reset"
=> "ABCD_oxox\"><title>Reset" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :057 > xx = /.*(?=\">)/.match(ref).to_s
=> "ABCD_oxox" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :058 >
```

So I know it works. However, in AppleScript, I can't seem to get it to work:

```
-- AS Begin

set RefID2 to "ABCD_oxox\"><title>Reset"
set xx to find text ".*?(?=\\\">)" in RefID2 with regxp and string result

-- AS end
```

error "No result was returned from some part of this expression." number -2763

I'm stumped... anybody got a clue on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Does the add-on work correctly. Have you tried something simple like ".*"

The following code works in Applescript :

```
set aa to "ABCD_oxox\"><title>Reset"
set aa to "puts /.*(?=\">)/.match(" & quoted form of aa & ").to_s"
do shell script "ruby -e " & quoted form of aa
```

You can easily wrap the above into a function.

Comment: Turns out, I needed to put on my reading glasses! The addition is regexp, not regxp. Once I spelled the addition correction, it started working. But, you have given me an idea on how to wrap Ruby commands into some AppleScripts I have.